# Split delimiter separated string and insert into a table in oracle 11

Tags: regex, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have delimiter separated input  string which can have around 40 tokens (the number may grow), I want to insert these value into a table using stored procedure in oracle 11;
What is the best way of doing it

> 1. create an SP with 40 IN parameters and use it to insert.
> 2. Create an SP with 1 IN parameter which will take that string and split the delimiter separated tokens and insert them into a table

If 2nd approach looks good then please suggest how to achieve it??

For example if a string is like `"abc,123,xyz,pqr,12"` (here delimiter is comma)
so after running the SP my table table1(A varchar2, B Number, C varchar2, D varchar2, E number ) should have entry like

```
A  | B | C | D | E
abc|123|xys|pqr |12
```

I came up with below solution be not sure about performance , is there any better way to do the same ?

```
declare
  string_to_parse varchar2(2000) := 'abc,123,xyz,pqr,12';
  A varchar2(4);
  B number;
  C varchar2(4);
  D varchar2(4);
  E number;
begin

  string_to_parse := string_to_parse||',';

   A  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_to_parse,'[^,]+', 1, 1);
   B  := TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_to_parse,'[^,]+', 1, 2));
   C  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_to_parse,'[^,]+', 1, 3);
   D  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_to_parse,'[^,]+', 1, 4);
   E  := TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_to_parse,'[^,]+', 1, 5));
   dbms_output.put_line('A ' || A || ' B ' || B || ' c ' || c || ' D ' || D || ' E ' || E);
--insert into table
end;
```

Comment: What this has to do with Java?

Comment: removed the tag java

Comment: Your unit / management must seriously consider upgrading your Oracle database to latest version(or at least to Oracle 11). Oracle 9 is primitive and outdated in today's world.

Comment: sorry in prod we will be using oracle 11..9 was on my local. edited question

Comment: I suppose the question is, why is the input a delimited string? At some point in the process you must have discrete data values. Why not keep them discrete and pass them to the database like that?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the splitting is a long way to the goal.
Considering that a target table could have a lot of columns (yes, 5 is to much to handle each of them in a distinct variable), I would suggest using schema dictionary to throw in a bit of flexibility.

Let's look at a procedure that takes two parameters: a table name and a string containing list of comma separated values.
Here it's supposed that table has only string, numeric and time columns. To implement a complete version add handling of all required data types in the beginning of procedure.

Pay attention that in the middle we split a string into a table of substrings using standard SQL approach:

```
select level as column_id, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(pi_values_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) as column_val 
  from dual connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(pi_values_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Here is the whole procedure:

```
  create or replace procedure myInsertInto(pi_table_name  char,
                                           pi_values_list char)
  is
    v_statement     varchar2(30000) := 'INSERT INTO %TABLE_NAME% (%COLUMNS_LIST%) VALUES (%VALUES_LIST%)';
    v_columns_list  varchar2(10000);
    v_values_list   varchar2(10000);
  begin

    SELECT LISTAGG(T.column_name, ',') within group (order by T.column_id) ,
           LISTAGG( -- implement specific types handling here
                    CASE
                    WHEN S.column_val IS NULL
                      THEN 'NULL'
                    WHEN T.data_type = 'NUMBER'
                      THEN S.column_val
                    WHEN T.data_type IN ('DATE', 'TIMESTAMP') 
                      THEN 'TIMESTAMP ''' || S.column_val || ''''
                    WHEN T.data_type like '%CHAR%' 
                      THEN '''' || S.column_val || ''''                    
                    ELSE 'NULL'
                    END, 
           ',') within group (order by T.column_id)
    into v_columns_list,
         v_values_list
    from user_tab_cols T,
         (select level as column_id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(pi_values_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) as column_val 
            from dual connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(pi_values_list, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) S
   where T.table_name = pi_table_name
     and T.column_id = S.column_id;

    if v_columns_list IS NULL then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not found columns for table ' || pi_table_name);
    end if;

    -- finalizing the statement
    v_statement := replace(v_statement, '%TABLE_NAME%', pi_table_name);      
    v_statement := replace(v_statement, '%COLUMNS_LIST%', v_columns_list);      
    v_statement := replace(v_statement, '%VALUES_LIST%', v_values_list);

    execute immediate v_statement;
  end;
  /
```

Then use it like this

```
create table MY_TABLE (
  col_a VARCHAR2(10),
  col_b NUMBER,
  col_c VARCHAR2(10),
  col_d DATE,
  col_E VARCHAR2(10) default 'DEFAULT'
);



begin
  myInsertInto('MY_TABLE', 'abc,123,xyz,2018-01-02 23:01:10,pqr' );
  myInsertInto('MY_TABLE', 'def,345,mkr' );
  myInsertInto('MY_TABLE', 'fgh' );
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

The first approach is a no-no.

The second may work.
Simply:

1. Assign your input string to variable s.

Now, in loop:

1. Exit the loop, if length of the s is 0
2. Find the first occurence of your delimiter (',') with instr. Assign it to X
3. If X = 0, then X := len(string) + 1
4. X := X - 1
5. If X > 0, then insert the substr(s, 1, X) into your table
6. If X > 0, then s := substr(s, X+1, len(s))

I didn't test it and there are obvious ways to optimize it (for example - instead of assigning substring back to s, you could store 'left end index' of currently parsed part.

But there is better approach - to do in pure sql.
Unfortunately, I don't know, whether your oracle version supports all the features, but give a try to this select:

```
with 
my_input_string as (
   select 'my,delimited,,,,,,input,string' s from dual
),
string_to_rows as (
   select trim(regexp_substr(s, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) col 
    from my_input_string
 connect by instr(my_input_string.s, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
)
select *
  from string_to_rows
 where col is not null
```

If it works (and by 'works' i mean - returns four rows), just use this in your insert.
Replace hardcoded string with procedure's parameter and that's it.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the code snippet is some how not working in oracle

Comment: Apparently your version does not support hierarchical queries and/or with clause.
The with clause is easy to get around - just change the query to use subqueries instead of CTEs.

Here you have some other tips, how to map delimited string into rows:
https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/

Comment: *"'The first approach is a no-no."* less of a no-no than passing concatenated strings around.

Comment: @APC If your input is concatenated string in the first place, you're not going to save the world anyway.
You've only delegated responsibility of splitting the string outside of the procedure (where you can make all the same mistakes as inside of it), and now you have a procedure with 40 parameters, 40 sets of values for the insert, and you have to modify your code at least in 3 places whenever the number of parameters grows (procedure call, procedure definition, and whatever-you-have in procedure body).
I agree with the sentiment, but the world is not perfect.

Comment: But the world does not start out with a comma delimited string. Databases deal with discrete data values and so do applications. Something concatenated those previously discrete values. That's the root of the problem.

Comment: Ok, so go ahead and convince the whole world to stop using csv files.

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest the input is a CSV file. And if it is a CSV file? Well, there are better ways to load those into a database.